# how to get maximum sub array in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
var maxSubArray = function(nums) {
    let sum = 0,
     result = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        sum = Math.max(0, sum + nums[i]);
        result = Math.max(sum, result);
    }
    return result ;
};

let nums = [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4];
console.log(maxSubArray(nums));
```

**Question**
Given an integer array nums, find the contiguous subarray (containing at least one number) which has the largest sum and return its sum.

```
Example:

    Input: [-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4],
    Output: 6
    Explanation: [4,-1,2,1] has the largest sum = 6.
```

**But my test case fail**

```
Input
[-1]
Output
0
Expected
-1
```

and one more test case fails

```
Input
[-2,-1]
Output
0
Expected
-1
```

Answer

```
var maxSubArray = function(nums) {
     let sum = 0,
        result = 0,
         max=nums[0];

    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        sum = Math.max(0, sum + nums[i]);
        result = Math.max(sum, result);
        if(nums[i] > max){
            max = nums[i];
        }
    }

    return result <=0 ? max :result ;
};
```

Comment: check if the maximum is actually positive - if not return maximum

Comment: great thanks ...!!

Comment: thanks it working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `result` should start at `-Infinity` (or at the value of the first item of the array), otherwise an array containing all negative numbers won't give a proper result. The calculation of `sum` inside the loop should also use `Math.max(nums[i], sum + nums[i]);`, otherwise if you pass `0` to `Math.max`, the current running total will always be at least 0, resulting in an incorrect answer when the passed array contains all negative values.

```js
var maxSubArray = function(nums) {
    let sum = 0,
     result = -Infinity;
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        sum = Math.max(nums[i], sum + nums[i]);
        result = Math.max(sum, result);
    }
    return result ;
};

console.log(
  maxSubArray([-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]),
  maxSubArray([-1]),
  maxSubArray([-2,-1]),
);
```

Comment: it's complexity in n^2

Comment: can we reduce if possible

Comment: Ok, change the initial `result` to `-Infinity`, and pass `nums[i]` to `Math.max` instead of `0`

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var maxSubArray = function(nums) {
         let sum = 0,
            result = -Infinity;

        for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            sum = Math.max(nums[i], sum + nums[i]);
            result = Math.max(sum, result);
        }

        return result ;
    };
   console.log(
  maxSubArray([-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4]),
  maxSubArray([-1]),
  maxSubArray([-2,-1]),
);
```

```html
   

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```